# IE Won't Work When Forms Are Involved

Tags: css, forms, internet-explorer

I have a pretty awesome looking template I'm making for my website, and I love it!  When I tested to make sure it worked in all five major browsers (IE,Firefox,Chrome,Opera,Safari), it worked great in ALL but IE!  The template works fine in all five browsers whenever the page does not have a `<form>` in it, but if a page does, such as the log-in page, it looks like a five year old drew it.

I was wondering if anyone else has ever had this problem, and if so, how'd you fix it?

By the way, this is what the  tag looks like:

```
    <form method="post" action="/themeChange.php">
```

As you can guess, /themeChange.php is the name of my page which is by far the worst looking.

Here is a URL to one page that is messing up:
http://www.allthemgames.com/login.php

And here is what it is SUPPOSED to look like:
http://www.allthemgames.com/home.php

Thanks for your help, and if you're reading this because you're experiencing the same problem, I hope we get the answer!

By the way, this problem is in IE6,IE7,IE8,and IE9.  I have not checked prior versions beyond this.

Comment: Showing some code would help you get an answer. Or a link to a site that shows the problem

Comment: You'll have to show your CSS and HTML code.  If not the full form, at least an element or two of the form.   I can only speculate that your using CSS that's not supported by IE7 and IE8.  IE9 does a decent job.  If you're shy on show code, try checking if you CSS is supported here: http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you don't have a doctype.  Without a doctype, IE will render in compatibility mode.  Add that.

Second, fix your validation errors.  Invalid markup is the #1 reason markup looks different between browsers.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.allthemgames.com%2Flogin.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks for the validator link!!  That is being SUPER helpful!  And also, I never knew that the doctype mattered.

Comment: @BoomGoesTheDynamite, for IE, the `doctype` MUST also have nothing above it, not even a blank line.